Why is a simple submodule ${}_{kG}S \leq {}_{kG}kG$ with $_{kG}S \simeq\ _{kG}k$ necessarily $k \cdot \bigl( \sum_{g \in G} g \bigr)$?
Let $G$ be a finite group, $k$ a field, and $kG$ the corresponding group algebra.
My question is:

When ${}_{kG}S$ is a simple submodule of the left regular module ${}_{kG}kG$ with $\dim_k(S) = 1$ and
$$_{kG}S \simeq\ _{kG}k$$ where the module structure of $k$ over $kG$ given by $g\cdot x:= x$ for all $ x \in k $,  why is
$$
{}_{kG}S = k \cdot \!\biggl(\, \sum_{g \in G} g \biggr)?
$$


Are you missing some other hypothesis? What about, e.g., the simple $1$-dimensional sign module in $G = S_n$ spanned by the element $\sum_{g \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn}(g),g$?

@Sammy Black Thank you very much; I don’t have any further assumptions at the moment.

The 1D submodules of the group algebra correspond to 1D reps, and the one you're specifying is the trivial rep. Generally a group has other 1D reps, such as the sign rep of $S_n$ Sammy mentions, so this is false as stated. Indeed, the 1D reps of a finite group correspond to the elements of the dual group of its abelianization. Thus, a group has no nontrivial 1D reps iff it is a perfect group. (Examples of perfect groups include simple groups.)

You need $G=[G,G]$ for this to hold in general. Selecting a suitable $k$ gives exceptions, but when for example $k=\Bbb{C}$ that's it.

Suppose $S$ is a $1$-dimensional $kG$-submodule of $kG$.
Let $v = \sum_{g \in G} \lambda(g) g$ be a non-zero vector in $S$, so $S$ is spanned by $v$.
Replacing $v$ by a scalar multiple we can assume $\lambda(1) = 1$.
For all $x \in G$, we have $xv = \mu(x) v$ for some non-zero scalar $\mu(x)$, and the map $\mu: G \rightarrow k^\times$ is a homomorphism from $G$ into the multiplicative group.
On the other hand $$xv = \sum_{g \in G} \lambda(g) xg = \sum_{g \in G} \lambda(x^{-1}g) g,$$ so $xv = \mu(x)v$ gives $\mu(x) \lambda(g) = \lambda(x^{-1}g)$ for all $x,g \in G$.
With $g = 1$ we get $\mu(x) = \lambda(x^{-1})$ for all $x \in G$.
So $\lambda$ is also a homomorphism $G \rightarrow k^\times$. The conclusion is that every $1$-dimensional subspace of $kG$ is spanned by $$\sum_{g \in G} \lambda(g) g$$ for some homomorphism $\lambda: G \rightarrow k^\times$.
Thus for example if $G = [G,G]$ (so every homomorphism $G \rightarrow k^\times$ is the identity), it is true that you just get the $1$-dimensional module spanned by $\sum_{g \in G} g$.
In general it may happen that there are other $1$-dimensional submodules, as mentioned in the comments.
